# Webview Android - Add listeners to HTML elements wthout using Javascript

Tags: android, android-webview

I would like to know if there is a way to the WebView component to support a generic listener for html components. For example, the html contains an img tag with a src attribute and I would like to handle this click on java side without using specific javascript, since I don't have access to the HTML being loaded.

I noticed that Android Studio prints logs into console, so maybe there is a listener for that I can override?

I've tried using the WebView onClick handler, but it is for the component and not its content, so I wasn't able to track the html element which triggered the click to get the src value, for example.

Also, the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method from WebViewClient doesn't work either, since it is just a click and not an url change. :(

Answer (score 0):

"I would like to handle this click on java side without using specific javascript, since I don't have access to the HTML being loaded."

Ah, but you do! You can use [evaluateJavaScript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String, android.webkit.ValueCallback)) to run some JavaScript on the page to set up the click handler you want.

Comment: I will take a look on that, thanks! Do you know if there is a possibility to handle them without JS? Because when I click on it the console prints a few lines, so maybe there is a method that I can override? :P